# Async Await Running Synchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to learn async/await and created the following test code, however it is running synchronously and I'm not sure why.

```
    class Program
    {                
        static void Main()
        {
            TestAsync testAsync = new TestAsync();
            testAsync.Run();

            Console.Read();
        }        
    }

    public class TestAsync
    {
        public async void Run()
        {
            Task<int> resultTask = GetInt();
            Console.WriteLine("2)");
            int x = await resultTask;
            Console.WriteLine("4)");
        }
        public async Task<int> GetInt()
        {
            Task<int> GetIntAfterLongWaitTask = GetIntAfterLongWait();
            Console.WriteLine("1)");
            int x = await GetIntAfterLongWaitTask;//Expecting execution to go back to Run() since it's not done yet.
            Console.WriteLine("3)");
            return x;
        }

        public async Task<int> GetIntAfterLongWait()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 500000000; i++)
            {
                if (i % 10000000 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }                
            }

            return 23;
        }
    }
```

Output is:

```
<long list of ints>
1)
3)
2)
4)
```

I expected it to be

```
<long list of ints>
1)
2)
3)
4)
```

With `1)` being somewhere amongst the long list of ints.

Why is it running synchronously?

Comment: `GetIntAfterLongWait` doesn't have any `await`s

Comment: The warning you should be seeing for `GetIntAfterLongWait` already told you this.

Comment: "All" that the `async` marking on a method does is allow you to write c# code inside that method that includes `await`s. By itself, it does *nothing* else.

Comment: I'm not going to VTC as duplicate, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44334060/15498) covers the ground quite well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confusingly enough, the `async` keyword will not turn your methods magically asynchronous. Instead, you can consider `async` methods as a setup for a state machine (see a detailed explanation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/hh191443(v=vs.110)#what-happens-in-an-async-method)), where you schedule the chain of operations by the `await` calls.

For that reason, your async methods must execute as fast as possible. Do not do any blocking operation in such a setup method. Your `GetIntAfterLongWait` method is a blocking operation and since it does not contain any `await`s the whole content will be executed immediately when the method is called (without any `await` there is nothing in the method to setup for an async continuation). There must be also a warning about that.

If you have a blocking operation, which you want to execute in the async method, a possible option is to schedule it by an `await Task.Run(() => MyLongOperation());` call.

So for example the following example will return immediately because there is nothing to execute before the first `await`. The return statement will be executed asynchronously as a continuation after the inner awaited task finished:

```
public async Task<int> GetIntAfterLongWait()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500000000; i++)
        {
            if (i % 10000000 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }                
        }
    });

    return 23;
}
```

For more details see the link above.

**Update:**

This version will print:

```
1)
2)
<long list of ints> - but 0 can be before even 1) as Task.Run uses another thread
3)
4)
```